# Как из асинхронного класса shell убрать su что бы команды выполнялись не из под рута?

Tags: java, классы, android-asynctask, su

```
public class execSHELL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {   
            protected String doInBackground(String... command) {  
                StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();            
                try {Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    Process process = rt.exec("su");
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                    for(int i = 0; i < command.length; i++) {
                    os.writeBytes(command[i] + "\n");
                    os.flush();}
                    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                    os.flush();
                    process.waitFor();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));     
                    String line = "";           
                    while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                        output.append(line + "\n");}
                    os.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}
                return output.toString();}              
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        //    if (result.equals("")) {  }
             }
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в лоб, то вместо

```
Process process = rt.exec("su");
```

Вызвать

```
Process process = rt.exec(command[0]);
```

А for крутить не 0, а с 1.